# How to accept both an absolute or relative path as a URL? (Java)

Tags: java, file, url, path

What I'm trying to do is creating a URL object with a valid path to a file (in my case it's a unix system but I'm not sure whether it will be used on any other OS). The path should be given as a String. I can't figure out how to get my code accept both absolute or relative paths. Can anyone help?

Comment: I guess you could do a `try {} catch () {}` and if the absolute path case doesn't work, see if you can make the relative path work.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a good workaround if there isn't any way Java can detect that itself.

Comment: I am unsure if the object has a way to check it, but if not I would think it would just be a try...catch.

Comment: Use `new URL(basleURL, relativeOrAbsolutePath)`. `new URL(new URL("http://a.com"), "relative")` returns `http://a.com/relative`.  `new URL(new URL("http://a.com"), "http://b.com")` returns `http://b.com`.